# How do I create an encrypted OpenPGP private key in Go?

Tags: encryption, go, pgp, openpgp

I would like to generate OpenPGP key pairs and encrypt them using 'passphrases' before exporting them. I would like to do so in Go, using its [openpgp package](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/openpgp). So far I have generated key pairs, exported them and successfully imported the public keys in GnuPG for encryption, using the simple wrapper linked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39626592/52439).

I still need to **encrypt the private keys using 'passphrases'** before exporting them in ASCII armor though. Could someone please provide me with an example or some hint on how to do this?

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Comment: No, in the end we dropped the idea of using Go as a language for that project altogether.

Comment: :/ I found another library which I'm using solely for generating keys, and go for everything else.

Comment: is this example good enough? I just searched on github: https://gist.github.com/jonatasnona/6b4ed853af7c8fc7ced5f6213c5acbac

Answer (score -1):

sample file in main.go next run:

`go mod init gpg`

`go mod tidy`

`go run main.go`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"

    "github.com/ProtonMail/gopenpgp/v2/crypto"
    "github.com/ProtonMail/gopenpgp/v2/helper"
)

func main() {
    var (
        name       = "Max Mustermann"
        email      = "max.mustermann@example.com"
        passphrase = []byte("LongSecret")
        rsaBits    = 2048 * 2
    )

    // RSA, string
    rsaKey, err := helper.GenerateKey(name, email, passphrase, "rsa", rsaBits)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(rsaKey)

    keyRing, err := crypto.NewKeyFromArmoredReader(strings.NewReader(rsaKey))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    publicKey, err := keyRing.GetArmoredPublicKey()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(publicKey)
}
```